# Redis data - interpretation of results

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm starting to work with a Redis database and I have been querying a key that is of type hash. I do an HSCAN to check some values and its format. I get the following results.

[image: results]

I was wondering if there is any way I can know what's the representation of this data. Is it hexadecimal, binary?. I was also wondering if there is any way to decode this, either by a client or some sort of Python script (I have seen some around but I don't know if they apply to this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised it's just a serialised object and I have to deserialised through Java